# Are there many irregular adjectives for the Latin comparison?

Tags: word-comparison, adjective, irregular-words, comparative

I just learned the comparison for adjectives. Most adjectives have regular conjugations (every case/grammatical gender has its own output). But I learned a few irregular adjectives as well (all in masculinum):

- bonus, melior, optimus (good, better, best)
- malus, peior, pessimus (bad, worse, worst)
- magnus, maior, maximus (big, bigger, biggest)
- parvus, minor, minimus (small, smaller, smallest)
- multi, plures, plurimi (much, more, most)

Am I missing any irregular adjectives, or have I learned all the irregular adjectives already?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me mention some things to complement your and TKR's lists.

First, the adjectives *iuvenis* and *senex* have the irregular comparatives *iunior* and *senior*.
These comparatives are rarely (if ever) used in neuter.
Neither adjective has a superlative.
For *senex*, the superlative can be replaced by that of *vetustus* (*vetustissimus*).
For *vetus*, comparatives and superlatives are often taken from *vetustus*.
I do not know how the missing superlative of *iuvenis* is typically replaced.

Some adjectives ending in *-dicus*, *-ficus* and *-volus* form comparative an superlative from *-dicent-*, *-ficent-* and *-volent-*.
For example:

- *maledicus, maledicentior, maledicentissimus*
- *magnificus, magnificentior, magnificentissimus*
- *benevolus, benevolentior, benevolentissimus*

For adjectives ending in *-eus*, *-ius* or *-uus* (not *-quus*) use *magis* or *maxime* to form comparative and superlative.
For example, *magis/maxime idoneus* instead of *idoneior/idoneissimus*.

There are adjectives coming from prepositions that only have comparative and superlative but no positive.
These are *prior/primus*, *posterior/postremus*, *superior/summus/supremus*, *inferior/infimus/imus*, *exterior/extremus*, *interior/intimus*, *citerior/citimus*, *ulterior/ultimus* and *propior/proximus*.

For adjectives ending in *-er*, the superlative is formed with *-rimus*.
For example:

- *pulcher, pulchrior, pulcherrimus*
- *liber, liberior, liberrimus*
- *acer, acrior, acerrimus*

The superlative *veterrimus* also has this ending.

Similarly, these six adjectives ending in *-ilis* form the superlative with *-limus*: *difficilis, dissimilis, facilis, gracilis, humilis, similis*.
For example, *dissimilis, dissimilior, dissimillimus*.

Answer (score 9):

Allen and Greenough list three more, but they are rare:

- nequam, nequior, nequissimus "worthless"
- frugi, frugalior, frugalissimus "useful"
- dexter, dexterior, dextimus "on the right, handy"

Comment: This is interesting. My Latin grammar (a Finnish one) does not mention these adjectives at all. My dictionary gives the adjective *frugalis* (for which *frugalior* and *frugalissimus* are regular), so one might also argue that *frugi* has no comparative or superlative at all. Nevertheless, those three adjectives you list are useful to keep in mind, including the peculiar comparison.